# Python dataframe drop rows which occur less frequently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with repeatedly occurring rows with different names. I want to delete less occurring rows. My data frame is very big. I am giving only a small size here.

**dataframe:**

```
df = 
         name     value
    0      A      10
    1      B      20
    2      A      30
    3      A      40
    4      C      50
    5      C      60
    6      D      70
```

In the above data frame B and D rows occurred fewer times. That is less than 1. I want to delete/drop all such rows that occur less than 2.

My code:

```
##### Net strings
net_strs = df['name'].unique().tolist()
strng_list = df.group.unique().tolist()
tempdf = df.groupby('name').count()
##### strings that have less than 2 measurements in whole data set
lesstr = tempdf[tempdf['value']<2].index
##### Strings that have more than 2 measurements in whole data set
strng_list = np.setdiff1d(net_strs,lesstr).tolist()
##### Removing the strings with less measurements
df = df[df['name']==strng_list]
```

My present output:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

My expected output:

```
         name     value
    0      A      10
    1      A      30
    2      A      40
    3      C      50
    4      C      60
```

Comment: Are you looking to drop rows with unique name ?

Comment: @Sushanth No. I want to drop rows that occur less frequently. In the above question, I said less than 2. I may wish to choose less than 3 as well. My question is representational only.

Comment: So for freq=1, drop B,D & for freq=2 drop C,B,D correct ?

Comment: @Sushanth That's correct.

Comment: Try `df.groupby('name').apply(lambda dd: dd if len(dd) > 1 else pd.DataFrame()).reset_index(drop=True)`. But this is likely slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could find the count of each element in name and then select rows only those rows having names that occur more than once.

```py
v = df.name.value_counts()
df[df.name.isin(v.index[v.gt(1)])]
```

**Output :**

```
    name    value
0   A   10
2   A   30
3   A   40
4   C   50
5   C   60
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this code should give you what you want.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('name').transform('count')
df2 = df.loc[df['count'] >= 2].drop(columns='count')
```

Comment: Adding to above answer, ```df[df.groupby('name').transform('count').gt(1)['value']]```

Comment: Personal warning, from experience, `groupby().transform()` can be extremely slow for big datasets

Answer (score 1):

You should use `value_counts()` to get the occurrence of each row, followed by slicing this series to get the name of the rows you can to drop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','A','A','C','C','D'],
                   'value':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]})
removals = df['name'].value_counts().reset_index()
removals = removals[removals['name'] > 1]['index'].values
```

Here, we're setting a threshold of 1, where all values that show up more than one will get selected, but this can obviously be a variable, or changed accordingly.

```
filtered_df = df[df['name'].isin(removals)]
print(filtered_df)
```

Output:

```
  name  value
0    A     10
2    A     30
3    A     40
4    C     50
5    C     60
```